# When I delete a unrelated sentence with printf, my program won't be run normally

Tags: c

In fact, I have almost complete the exercise 5-13, but it occurs a problem which  so weird that I can't find what mistake I make:
When I delete 13th line of my code,i.e. printf("%d\n",argc);
My program won't run normally.And it meet a problem that: when I enter ./tail -10

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXSIZE 1000

/* prints the last linesof its input,and the n's default value is 10 */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int atoi(char*);
    int readlines(char *lineptr[], int maxlines);/* read the input to the lineptr */
    int n = 10;
    int i;
    char *lineptr[MAXSIZE];/* store the the point of input lines */
    int lines;
    printf("%d\n",argc);
    while(--argc > 0){
            if((*++argv)[0] == '-') {
                    n = atoi(++*argv);
                    printf("%d\n",n);
            }
            else {
                    printf("Error input\n");
                    return -1;
            }
    }
    lines = readlines(lineptr,MAXSIZE);// lines is the the actual lines of input */
    if(lines > n) /* print ten the last n lines */
            for(i = lines - n;i <= lines -1;i++)
                    printf("%s\n",lineptr[i]);
    else
            for(i=0;i < lines;i++)  /* print all the input */
                    printf("%s\n",lineptr[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

readline.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLEN 1000     /* max length of any input line */

int getLine(char *, int);
char *alloc(int);
/* readlines: read input lines */
int readlines(char *lineptr[], int maxlines)
{
    int len,nlines;
    char *p,line[MAXLEN];

    while((len = getLine(line,MAXLEN)) > 0)
            if(nlines >= maxlines || (p = alloc(len)) == NULL)
                    return -1;
            else {
                    line[len-1] = '\0';
                    strcpy(p,line);
                    lineptr[nlines++] = p;
            }
    return nlines;
}

int getLine(char *s, int lim)
{
    int i;
    int c;
    for(i = 0;i<lim-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c != '\n';i++)
            *s++ = c;
    if(c=='\n') {
            *s++ = c;
            i++;
    }
    *s = '\0';
    return i;
}
```

alloc.c

```
#define ALLOCSIZE 10000

static char allocbuf[ALLOCSIZE];
static char *allocp = allocbuf;

char *alloc(int n)
{
    if(allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE - allocp >=n) {
            allocp += n;
            return allocp -n;
    }
    else
            return 0;
}
```

atoi.c

```
#include <ctype.h>

int atoi(char *p)
{
    int sign,n;
    int c;
    while(isspace(*p))
            p++;
    if((c = (*p)) == '+' || c == '-')
                    p++;
    sign = c == '-' ? -1 : 1;
    for(n = 0;isdigit(c=*p);p++)
            n = n * 10 + (c - '0');
    return n * sign;
}
```

Comment: why not use the standard header files?

Comment: when I enter ./tail -10 <tail.c , the shell rill print "5" and "Segment default", while if I enter ./tail <tail.c. It can print the true result.

Comment: it is `readline` or `readlines()`, actualy?

Comment: But If I leave the 13th code there, everything seems normally, and it can print the true results whatever I input.

Comment: Er,I think that some repeat will good for my studying.

Comment: What is `readlines` ?

Comment: Hmm, I have write it refer the front codes of TCPL. Maybe the problem isn't there.

Comment: If removing the source line you designated changes the program's behavior in ways other than avoiding the expected effect of that line itself, then you have a flaw elsewhere in your code.  Although I don't particularly *like* some aspects of your code, I don't see anything in what you presented that actually looks wrong.  The `readlines()` function is suspicious, though.

Comment: I have just edit my question and add my codes of readlines. I'm so sorry that I made it so slowly

Comment: @MaryWee Please read [ask]. Your title, if nothing else, says nothing about the problem you're having.

Comment: Now I have upload all of my codes

Comment: Er, I 'm so sorry. I am a newer to StackOverflow, I will read it and notice as k my question correctly next time. Thank you for point that..

Comment: `++*argv` <-- That's a really bad idea. Quit altering `argv` and just use simple indexing. Your code will be much simpler and easier to maintain.

Comment: I will notice it next time, thank you very much for point the shortcut with my codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an unitialized variable in `readLines`:

```
int len,nlines;       // nlines not initialized
char *p,line[MAXLEN];

while((len = getLine(line,MAXLEN)) > 0)
        // nlines used here
        if(nlines >= maxlines || (p = alloc(len)) == NULL)
```

Uninitialized local variables have undefined contents, so attempting to use that value leads to [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to set `nlines=0` when you declare it.

I was able to quickly find this issue with [valgrind](http://valgrind.org), which gave me the following output:

```
==8219== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==8219==    at 0x40076A: readlines (x1.c:48)
==8219==    by 0x4006CE: main (x1.c:27)
==8219==
==8219== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==8219==    at 0x4007C2: readlines (x1.c:53)
==8219==    by 0x4006CE: main (x1.c:27)
==8219==
```

Comment: Yeah!The problem is there!Now,my program can print the true result. And it seems that the valgrind is a good stool, I will study how to use it.Thank you very much.!However, I still have a question that why when I add a unrelated statement with printf before the call to the function readline,it won't occur errors while my program running?

Comment: @MaryWee That's part of undefined behavior.  When `nlines` is not initialized, using it to index `lineptr` can land outside of the array's bounds.  Writing to that invalid index means you write to memory you shouldn't be.  And when memory corruption occurs, programs behave unpredictably.  This includes programs crashing or not crashing when adding an unrelated function call.

Comment: Oh, so it is! I'll keep that in mind. Thank you for your enthusiastic helping.